# Forcing PHP to download file via browser

Tags: php, file, download, header

I'm currently trying to make a file download in the user's browser but have so far been unable to make it happen.

I've looked at other answers on stackoverflow.com and so far haven't found anything that has solved my problem.

My process is as follows:

I create the filename and filepath, then set headers:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$currentDateTime = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$filename = "{$name}_{$currentDateTime}.csv";
$filepath = $rootfull . "/{$filename}";

// Set headers
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filepath . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath)); 
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

I then create the file and start writing to it:

```
// Write header
fputcsv($output, $header);
fputcsv($output, array()); // Empty line

// Write column names
$column_headers = array_keys(array_flip($columns));

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}

echo readfile($filepath);
die();
```

The file gets generated and written to the specified location (in this case `/var/www/<project>/<filename>.csv` without any indication to the user that anything has happened. No download dialog, nothing.

If anyone can spot a problem with my code or my process, please point it out and preferably suggest a better/alternative way of doing it, any help at all is welcome at this point.

Comment: You create the file *before* sending the headers right?

Comment: just `readfile($file_url);` no `echo`

Comment: @ficuscr you wouldn't need to create the file before sending the headers, just before you try to readfile back to the user.

Comment: Also, you can `fopen('php://output', 'w')` which opens php's output stream and then `fputcsv` to that. Then you don't need a temporary file on disk. With this, you will have issues if two people try to download at the same time.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yeah but Content-Length 0 then

Comment: I assume you are talking about the header. As it is described above, content-length is already 0 because you create an empty file, send out the headers (which contains a content-length and gets the filesize of the empty file), then build the file and read it back out to the user. Maybe that's your issue, content length is zero and so the browser stops looking for more.

Comment: If that is the case, I would suggest using something like [tempnam](https://php.net/tempnam) which will create a unique temporary file and return the path to it. Then fopen that, fputcsv, read size, send headers and readfile back.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I've moved the code that sets the headers to just before `readfile()`, and have removed the `echo` from it. Using `php://output` results in nothing being written to disk, and no download, and the old way still only results in the file being saved to disk without downloading. Have checked - Content-Length has value 568. Filenames are already fairly unique, using the date and time stamp as part of the file name.

Comment: As ficuscr mentioned below, it might be your browser. I know I've seen issues in the past with ms office "trying" to be helpful and intercepting downloads to files that are set to open in office. It caused a lot of issues for us as office would intercept the download and prompt the user to open in office. Then office would make it's own web request to download the file but not send over the cookie data or session id. Meaning the user would not be logged in. We fixed it by changing the content-type header to a `application/octet-stream` header to force a download instead of the actual type.

Comment: Also, the `php://output` is to not write a file to disk and allow you to still use the file io functions like `fputcsv`. You wouldn't be able to use the `content-length` header as the output would be sent immediately. And the name may be unique enough for now, but if you are planning on having any traffic to the site and hit that file, you would be better off doing it right with a temp file. If you are planning on not having more that one or two people on the site at a time (e.g. admin panels don't have much traffic), then this would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If no benefit (poor mans cache) to writing to disk then maybe something like this writing to buffer:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dump_' . date('Ymd') . '.csv"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$this->outputCSV($results);
exit(); //->

public function outputCSV($data, $useKeysForHeaderRow = true)
{
    if ($useKeysForHeaderRow) {
        array_unshift($data, array_keys(reset($data)));
    }
    $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    foreach($data as $v) {
        fputcsv($outputBuffer, $v);
    }
    fclose($outputBuffer);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately this makes no difference - the file still does not get downloaded in the browser.

Comment: Strange.  Copied that from code that is in use.  Maybe your browser is the issue.

Comment: It's more than possible, thank you for the answer anyways though, hopefully it helps someone in the future :)